# How to locate a file in command prompt without having to direct to the specific folder

Tags: windows, command-line, command, command-prompt

There must be a more effecient way to this, why can't I just type in the files name in the command line and expect the computer to find it? Right now I'm just paddling back and forward with the 'CD' and 'CD ..' commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command which searches for the file in command prompt.

```
dir package.json /s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use command find -path *content/docs/file.xml to find out the file.If it works please inform me the same.Thanks